# vb.net trim word from end of string

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am trying to run an SQL query in my vb.net application using a loop

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE "
For m = 1 To num_array
    SQL = SQL & "type = '" & array(m, 1) & "' OR "
Next
```

but its showing an `OR` at the end.

how can i trim this last `OR` from my query?

Comment: Don't do this. Use parameterized queries instead. otherwise you are risking  [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Those types of SQL engines/parameter helpers rarely simplify code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems a job for a StringBuilder

```
Dim sql = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ")
For m = 1 To num_array
    sql.Append("type = '" & array(m, 1) & "' OR ")
Next

If num_array > 0 Then
    sql.Length -= 4
End If
```

However you should pay special care to your string concatenation. It seems that your array doesn't contain numbers but string because you are putting everything between single quotes and this means that your type field is a string not a number.
Of course I hope that your array content is not directly inserted by your user otherwise you have a big security risk called Sql Injection. Anyway look at how to build a parameterized query.

Something like this

```
Dim prms = New List(Of SqlParameter)()
Dim num_Array = 4
Dim sql = New StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ")
For m = 1 To num_array
    sql.Append("type = @p" & m & " OR ")
    prms.Add(New SqlParameter("@p" & m, array(m, 1)))
Next

If num_array > 0 Then
    sql.Length -= 4
End If 
Dim cmd = new SqlCommand(sql.ToString(), connection)
cmd.Parameters.AddRange(prms.ToArray())
```